# Reynolds number in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, turbulence

Does the relativistic counterpart of the Reynolds number exist, and how can find it?
And what is the dissipative term in Einstein equations?

Comment: In other terms, Einstein's equations can have turbulent dynamics in regions near black holes during the merger?